# HTML field minimum valuse using java script

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a form that has two fields `stationerytype` and `stationeryrqstqty`.The `stationeryrqstqtyfield` of the form accepts the number. The minimum number which can be entered in this field(QTY) depends upon the value of the `stationerytype` field i.e. If the `stationerytype` field value is 'pencil' then the minimum value property of the `stationeryrqstqty` field should be 5 and if it is 'notepad' then the minimum property of the `stationeryrqstqty` field should be 10. I am doing it by the given code but it's not working.it gives always 1,2,3.......

```
<td>
   <input  type="text" name="stationerytype[]" id="stationerytype" class="option1 form-control" autocomplete="off"  required>
</td>
<td>
   <input type="NUMBER" name="stationeryqtyrqst[]" id="stationeryqtyrqst" class="form-control" required >
</td>
<script>
    var options = document.querySelectorAll(".option1");
    options.forEach(function(option) {
      option.addEventListener("change", function() {
        calculatingMinimunQuantity(option);
      });
    });
    
    function calculatingMinimunQuantity(option) {
      var minimum = 0;
      var value = option.value;
      if (value === "PENCIL") {
        minimum = "5";
        step1="5";
      } else if (value === "NOTEPAD") {
        minimum = "10";
        step1="10";
      }
      //   getting the quantity input field
      option.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("min", minimum);
       option.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("step", step1);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: your `option1` input field doesn't have a nextSibling. it is the only element inside the `<td>`

Comment: @dehart In his case, the two `<td>` elements are outside a table and even outside a `tr` element, which makes them useless, modern browsers will not render them and will only render the content inline as siblings. I'm not saying that this is right, but at least it is not the cause of his issue.

Comment: I assume the OP only pasted the relevant part since the name fields end with "[]" and the `change` event is added in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix the issue by usin a `keyup` event instead of a `change` event:

```js
  var options = document.querySelectorAll(".option1");
    options.forEach(function(option) {
      option.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        calculatingMinimunQuantity(option);
      });
      option.nextElementSibling.addEventListener('change', evt => {
        if (+evt.target.value < +evt.target.min) evt.target.value = evt.target.min
      });
    });
    
    function calculatingMinimunQuantity(option) {
      var minimum = 0, step1 = 0;
      var value = option.value;
      if (value === "PENCIL") {
        minimum = "5";
        step1="5";
      } else if (value === "NOTEPAD") {
        minimum = "10";
        step1="10";
      }
      //   getting the quantity input field
      option.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("min", minimum);
      option.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("step", step1);
      
}
```

> Note: the event listener is used to ensure the user doesn't enter a value less than the min value